# Python import ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, selenium, import, module

when i run my code in pycharm - everything is ok. But when i try run my code in cmd I'm getting an error:

File "E:\programowanie\automatyzacja\otomoto\tests\FooterLinks.py", line 4, in 
from otomoto.pages.HomePage import HomePageLocators
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'otomoto'

This is my
[Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wTof.png)

Import code:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from otomoto.pages.HomePage import HomePageLocators
```

Comment: if you navigate to the automatyzacja directory and then run `python3 -m otomoto.main` does that work?

Comment: E:\programowanie\automatyzacja>py -m otomoto.main
Hi, PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

try installing **otomoto** by using this command:-

```
pip install otomoto
```

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement otomoto (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for otomoto